# Functional analysis linear normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a linear normed space with infinite dimension and $K$ is a subset of $X$ which is compact.Proof that the interior of $K$ is empty.

I have no idea how to work I tried the topological of compactness but nothing...

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the non-compactness of the unit ball in $X$, whenever $X$ is an infinite-dimensional normed linear space. This in turn is a consequence of the Riesz lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma.

Using this, you can construct a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $\|x_n\| = 1$ for each $n$ that contains no convergent subsequence, showing the unit ball is non (sequentially) compact. If $K \subset X$ has nonempty interior, it contains a ball, which is just a translated and scaled copy of the unit ball, which is not compact.

Comment: Ok thank you sir. You have helped me a lot